# MVC indexController not using the correct action

Tags: php, model-view-controller, autoload

I have two Actions in my IndexController.

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->view->setVars([
        'name' => 'Stefan',
    ]);
}

public function testAction()
{
    $this->view->setVars([
        'name' => 'testOutput',
    ]);
}
```

When going to call my index page

> https://localhost/index/

It does output the name that i set in my  `views/index/index.php`

```
<h1>Hello <?php echo $name ?></h1>
```

And i do get the output

> Hello Stefan

**Problem:**

If i got to

> https://localhost/index/test

I also get the same output even tho i cleary stated something else in my `testAction`

So he Acces the `indexAction` even if im in not calling the Action in my browser.

What i would want is, since i have `echo $name;` in my test.php file.

That i get the output

> **testOutput**

Here would be my Autoloader.

Thank you in advance.

```
    <?php
// simple autoloader
spl_autoload_register(function ($className) {
    if (substr($className, 0, 4) !== 'Mvc\\') {
        // not our business
        return;
    }
    $fileName = __DIR__.'/'.str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, substr($className, 4)).'.php';
    if (file_exists($fileName)) {
        include $fileName;
    }
});
// get the requested url
$url      = (isset($_GET['_url']) ? $_GET['_url'] : '');
$urlParts = explode('/', $url);
// build the controller class
$controllerName      = (isset($urlParts[0]) && $urlParts[0] ? $urlParts[0] : 'index');
$controllerClassName = '\\Mvc\\Controller\\'.ucfirst($controllerName).'Controller';
// build the action method
$actionName       = (isset($urlParts[1]) && $urlParts[1] ? $urlParts[1] : 'index');
$actionMethodName = $actionName.'Action';



try {
    if (!class_exists($controllerClassName)) {
        throw new \Mvc\Library\NotFoundException();
    }
    $controller = new $controllerClassName();
    if (!$controller instanceof \Mvc\Controller\Controller || !method_exists($controller, $actionMethodName)) {
        throw new \Mvc\Library\NotFoundException();
    }
    $view = new \Mvc\Library\View(__DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'views', $controllerName, $actionName);
    $controller->setView($view);
    $controller->$actionMethodName();
    $view->render();
} catch (\Mvc\Library\NotFoundException $e) {
    http_response_code(404);
    echo 'Page not found: '.$controllerClassName.'::'.$actionMethodName;
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    http_response_code(500);
    echo 'Exception: <b>'.$e->getMessage().'</b><br><pre>'.$e->getTraceAsString().'</pre>';
}
```

EDIT:

It really doesnt matter what i action i call after the index. it can be index/asdsad

And he still goes to the main indexAction.

It doesnt even say that he can't find the action.

EDIT2:

Output from `var_dump($url,$urlParts,$controllerName,$actionMethodName)`

```
    string(0) ""
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(0) ""
}
string(5) "index"
string(11) "indexAction"
```

Comment: Can you put a `die($actionName);` in your autoloader and check what is the value you are getting?

Comment: Everything is index.

Comment: So, if `$actionName` is `index`, `$controller->$actionMethodName();` will surely call `indexAction()` all the time.

Comment: So how am i able to fix this ? I really am stuck here.

Comment: Where can I find this MVC so that I can reproduce this issue at my end?

Comment: https://github.com/spoehner/mvc-example/tree/v0.5

Comment: Ok, let me see.

Comment: I tested it and I actually get a `Page not found` error instead of `Hello Stefan` for `https://localhost/index/test`. I came to know why this issue occurs. I will let you know,but before that, can you please check again if you are getting this error or is it still printing `Hello Stefan`? Can you edit your post and share your `views` folder structure with me?